# Submitting an app to the App Store that uses Firebase

Tags: firebase, app-store, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, appstore-approval

I had a quick question about submitting an app to the app store when it uses Firebase. I wanted to know if there is anything I need to do on the Firebase side to enable the database for anyone to use. Or can I just go through the normal process of submitting an app and assume that the database will be working for a tester or any user that downloads the app? In short do I have to enable something on the Firebase side for it to work globally for any user?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is nothing specific in the Firebase Database that makes it different between the app in development, testing or live on the app store.

Comment: thank you for telling me i can go ahead and submit my app now!