# Upload the app to AppStore which contains firebase

Tags: ios

Can I publish the app which contains firebase to AppStore ? Does google approve of this ?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't they?

Comment: Huh.. You sure can, what exactly are you concerned about?

Comment: That Google do not give ne some piercings that I use their database and don’t pay them anything

Comment: For example : to pay them if my app would cost 1 dollar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload your app with firebase to Apple store.

There is nothing specific in the Firebase Database that makes it different between the app in development, testing or live on the app store.

you can check similar question at here [Submitting an app to the App Store that uses Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667250/submitting-an-app-to-the-app-store-that-uses-firebase)